# Creating a dynamic entry list (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, internet-explorer, ecmascript-5

So basically I'm trying to create an ordered list that keeps track of the numbers entered into a text box and displays a sum of all the numbers in a correlating array. Unfortunately I don't have access to the code right now because it's on a different computer, but I can provide pusedo-code. This is what I'm trying to do.

1. User enters a number `value` into an `input` element and pressed an enter `button`.
2. Enter `button` takes this `value`and adds it to an `array` AND adds this value to an `ordered list` to be displayed as a list of entered values.
3. Display sum/accumulated value of the array in a `<h3>` element.
4. Be able to delete dynamically created `li` elements `onclick`.
5. Update and display the array and `<h3>` upon element deletion or addition.

If there is a better approach to doing this please drop the code. I'm not an expert on JS so feel free to explain in depth.

Comment: do not add it one time to the array and one in the DOM. Just have a function that renders the array and the sum in the dom and call it whenever you add/remove a value to the array.

Comment: "*Unfortunately I don't have access to the code right now because it's on a different computer...*" I'd suggest deleting this question for now, then editing, updating and reopening it once you have access to the [mcve] code. As it is the question is rather too open-ended and an opinion based thought experiment.

Comment: The user fills the array by typing a number and  pressing enter. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @DavidThomas the computer is at work. I can't export files from my work computer, I can only manage them while there, which is why I can't provide the code unless I simply create another example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a function to refresh values, which will be called both when an element is added and when an element is removed. Your array can be redefined on all these occasions, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="enter(parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value))">
<ol id="list">
</ol>
<h3 id="output">

</h3>
<h3 id="sum">

</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
var values = [];
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var sum = document.getElementById("sum");

function refreshValues() {
    values = [];
    var lis = list.querySelectorAll("li");
    for (var li of lis) values.push(parseInt(li.innerText));
    output.innerText = "Output: " + values.join(",");
    var sumVal = 0;
    for (var val of values) sumVal += val;
    sum.innerText = "Sum: " + sumVal;
}

function enter(value) {
    var liItems = list.querySelectorAll("li");
    var text = "";
    for (var li of liItems) {
        var currentValue = parseInt(li.innerText);
        if (value < currentValue) {
            text += '<li onclick="remove(this);">' + value + "</li>";
            value = undefined;
        }
        text += li.outerHTML;
    }
    if (value !== undefined) {
        text += '<li onclick="remove(this);">' + value + '</li>';
    }
    list.innerHTML = text;
    refreshValues();
}

function remove(what) {
    what.remove();
    refreshValues();
}
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3bxqkoh/2/)

EDIT

To Comply to old browsers, we need to get rid of for..of cycles:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="enter(parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value))">
<ol id="list">
</ol>
<h3 id="output">

</h3>
<h3 id="sum">

</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
var values = [];
var list = document.getElementById("list");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var sum = document.getElementById("sum");

function refreshValues() {
    values = [];
    var lis = list.querySelectorAll("li");
    for (var liIndex = 0; liIndex < lis.length; liIndex++) {
        values.push(parseInt(lis[liIndex].innerText));
    } 
    output.innerText = "Output: " + values.join(",");
    var sumVal = 0;
    for (var valIndex = 0; valIndex < values.length; valIndex++) sumVal += values[valIndex];
    sum.innerText = "Sum: " + sumVal;
}

function enter(value) {
    var liItems = list.querySelectorAll("li");
    var text = "";
    for (var liIndex = 0; liIndex < liItems.length; liIndex++) {
        var currentValue = parseInt(liItems[liIndex].innerText);
        if (value < currentValue) {
            text += '<li onclick="remove(this);">' + value + "</li>";
            value = undefined;
        }
        text += liItems[liIndex].outerHTML;
    }
    if (value !== undefined) {
        text += '<li onclick="remove(this);">' + value + '</li>';
    }
    list.innerHTML = text;
    refreshValues();
}

function remove(what) {
    what.remove();
    refreshValues();
}
</script>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaoqe0j8/)

Comment: This is basically what I've been asking for! Will this work with older versions of IE?

Comment: @CouchMango it should work. Please, test it and if it works in your IE browser, then accept this answer as the correct answer. If there are some problems/errors that you might encounter in those old browsers, then please let me know. I've tried to avoid using ES6 features.

Comment: I will test and let you know!

Comment: An error occurred while running the code. "expected ';'". It occurred in the refreshValues() function inside of the for loop, for(var li (Error is here) of lis) {...} ; (3rd line of the function)

Comment: @CouchMango good point, sorry about that. I have initially used for..of cycles, that is an ES6 feature. Now I have got rid of it. I have edited my answer. Can you test the second script?

Comment: Ok, so the updated code runs, but it doesn't do what it's supposed to be doing. When I enter a value into the text box and click the enter button, it displays "Output: 0" and not the number I just entered. It also doesn't accumulate or visually update the elements :(

Comment: @CouchMango unfortunately I cannot reproduce it, since I have no access to these browsers. Try out BabelJS to generate code for older browsers. Also, it would be great if you could check what parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value) is in your console. It might be something with parseInt, unfortunately, I cannot check it.

Comment: I will definitely check that out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @CouchMango you are welcome. If you still encounter problems, then we might need an IE emulator so we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have an array of numbers.

```
var numbers = [];
```

on each button click you get value from your input like this.

```
var value = document.getElementByTagName('input').value;
```

then this value you push to an array numbers.

```
numbers.push(value);
```

display all the items inside li:

```
numbers.forEach(function(element) {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(element);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  node.onclick =  removeItem(index) {
   numbers.splice(index, 1);
  };
  document.getElementTagName("ul").appendChild(node);
});
```

Then display the sum of this array inside a h3.

```
document.getElementByTagName("h3").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(myFunc);
function myFunc(total, num) {
  return total - num;
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Sad part is I'm using an old version of IE that doesn't support the => operand

Comment: @CouchMango l edited the answer and now you have no issues with browser supporting es6.

Comment: Nice answer, however, the question asks for ordered list, which seem to refer to an ol tag.

Comment: I ended up giving up sadly. I may try this again in the future when I'm more knowledgeable on the subject.